# AngularJS - Dependency injection on controllers module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Having real issues wrapping my head around an issue I'm having with Angular. I'm trying to set up a multi-page app with routing. My app.js looks a little something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularLocalStorage', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'authControllers', 'authServices', 'eventControllers', 'eventServices']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/events.html',
            controller: 'EventListController'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });

...
```

I'm attempting to make my module - app depend on eventControllers, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DeventControllers%26p1
```

This leads me to believe that it can't load eventController module for whatever reason.

My controllers.js looks a little something like this:

```
(function () {
    var authControllers = angular.module('authControllers', []);
    var eventControllers = angular.module('eventControllers', []);

    eventControllers.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('events', { // state for showing all events
            url: '/events',
            templateUrl: 'partials/events/list.html',
            controller: 'EventListController'
        }).state('viewMovie', { //state for showing single event
            url: '/events/:id/view',
            templateUrl: 'partials/events/single.html',
            controller: 'EventViewController'
        }).state('newMovie', { //state for adding a new event
            url: '/events/new',
            templateUrl: 'partials/events/create.html',
            controller: 'EventCreateController'
        }).state('editMovie', { //state for updating a event
            url: '/events/:id/edit',
            templateUrl: 'partials/events/edit.html',
            controller: 'EventEditController'
        });
    }).run(function($state) {
        $state.go('events'); //make a transition to events state when app starts
    });
```

I'm sure the answer is very simple, and I'm missing something basic, but I'd really appreciate any pointers.

The eventControllers module is only declared inside the controllers.js, could this be an issue?

Comment: Is that your entire `controllers.js` file? It looks like you never finished the IIFE: `}());`.

Comment: Not the entire controller, no, just the start of it. I figured the relevant code would be there.

Comment: Hmmm, my other thought would be to double check `index.html` and make sure you're referencing all the necessary `.js` files. This simple issue has tripped me up numerous times.

Comment: Check the order you are loading your scripts also.  Make sure you load angular first, then your controllers.

Comment: Why are you using ngRoute and ui-router in the same app? Where is your dependency on ui-router?